# Rearranging Dataframe date

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, reindex

How do I rearrange dates after importing a csv file, such that the most recent date is at the bottom and the oldest date is at the top?

I have tried using reindex but it doesn't work.

hello Nukesor, the date for example will be..

```
 Date          Price
 5-2-2017    15.24
 4-2-2017    18.21
 3-2-2017    19.11
 2-2-2017    20.28
 1-2-2017    17.00
```

Now i will like to put 5-2-2017 at the bottom

Thanks guys.

Comment: How exactly does the date in your dataframe look like? What type are your entries in the date row?
You might just need to call `df['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(df.Date)` and then sort by this column.

Comment: Hi Nukesor i have re-edited the question. Please take a look and kindly give your feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))\
       .sort_values('Date')

print(df)

        Date  Price
4 2017-01-02  17.00
3 2017-02-02  20.28
2 2017-03-02  19.11
1 2017-04-02  18.21
0 2017-05-02  15.24
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.sort_values('Date', ascending = True, inplace=True)
```

First line converts date to comprehensible datetime format for the dataframe. Second line sorts the values in ascending order. Without first line order would be as a string, and that is not the behaviour expected.